# Optimization practice dealing with points on a line

Tags: calculus, optimization

Find the point on the line $y = x + 2$ that is nearest to the point $(1,1)$. The shortest distance from point to point.

I honestly don't even know where to begin with this one.

Comment: @AlexBecker: Given that this question is tagged [tag:calculus] and the question to which you linked does not have a calculus-based answer (only geometric answers), I'm not sure that's a good choice of question to close this as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  If you want to use calculus, let $x$ be the horizontal coordinate of the point on the line.  Then the point is $(x,x+2)$.  You can calculate the distance from this to $(1,1)$ as a function of $x$, set the derivative to $0$.

Alternately, the shortest distance is along a perpendicular.  Do you know the relation between the slope of a line and the slope of the perpendicular?  Make a line through $(1,1)$ with that slope and find the intersection with your line.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, how would I create a function out of that? I'm trying to picture it, but I think I'm overlooking something really simple.

Comment: @Math_Phase:   The distance from $(1,1)$ to an arbitrary point on the line is $d=\sqrt{(1-x)^2+(1-(x+2))^2}$.  You can take $\frac{dd}{dx}$ and set it to $0$.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked using the distance formula. Thank you

Comment: @Math_Phase Also note that often it is easier (i.e. less formulas to write) to calculate the point where $d^2$ attend it's minimum.